# trigger Jquery function after an auto focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, focus

is it possible to trigger a function after an autofocus? I tried but when my textarea get the autofocus i need to click away then to click again on my textarea to trigger the function

my code is :

```
$('#test').focus();
$('#test').focus(function() {
  alert('ok');
});
```

Comment: First bind your handler and then focus on the element.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. Please give more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try swapping the code around. You're event wasn't attached to the test element the first time you call `focus()`

```
$('#test').focus(function() {
  alert('ok');
});
$('#test').focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are setting the trigger **after** you set the focus.

Rearrange your code and this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The .focus() method has two different meanings based on the parameters it is passed.

In your first statement.

```
$('#test').focus();
```

This is setting the focus to the element with ID test.

Your second statement though

```
$('#test').focus(function() {
   alert('ok');
});
```

What is happening here is jQuery is attaching an event handler to the focus event of the element. I suggest adding your event handlers when the DOM is loaded, then calling the .focus() event when required (which will trigger the alert).

```
$(function(){
   $('#test').focus(function() {
       alert('ok');
   });
});
```